# Getting an Unable access api , http error 403

Tags: reactjs, postman, swagger

I'm a beginner react developer and this, I’m supposed to implement some custom rest APIs provided by the client but I’m getting an:

> “access to “API” denied , you don’t have authorization, http error 403”

I wasn’t provided with any documentation only API links

I'm a complete beginner and I’ve never worked with custom APIs before, my question is how to access the API and use it, is there a specific thing I should ask for like a token or key and how to use it to access  them?

Comment: Some APIs need an access token, some need a username and password, some need this, some need that.  We can't tell you what this specific API needs.  Only the API provider can tell you that.

Comment: It is physically impossible to call an API with just *API links*, and zero formal documentation. Even if you had 10 years of experience with APIs you would not be able to do this. Try reaching out to the team who provide the API and see if they have formal documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to use a REST API, a formal description of the API may be provided by the API developers as either a [Swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/) file or an [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) file.

So I would suggest first requesting if such a file is available.

You also need information from the API developers about authentication and authorization to access the API.

Depending on how that's implemented, you may need a set of credentials (e.g. username and password), and a separate API endpoint to call (e.g. /authentication, or /login) where you pass the credentials and get back an API token (for example).

So this information should be provided by the API developers.

Incidentally, a HTTP 403 response indicates the request is unauthorized.
A HTTP 401 response indicates the request lacks authentication (i.e. no API token or key provided in the request).